# HDMI Audio wont work

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have read many things on trying to configure HDMI output on the forums, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I am running an AMD 8350 and ASUS Sabertooth motherboard with Nvidia Gforce 760. Here is a list of solutions I have tried so far
-updating/reinstalling drivers (currently running 346). 
-installing pavucontrol and configuring HDMI output
-going into alsamixer and turning on s/pdif(in fact I turned everything on to be sure)
-unistalling and reinstalling pulseaudio 
    I know that the television I am outputting to is not the problem because windows outputs the audio just fine on the same TV when I switch over. The only thing that I can think of is that I did not configure things correctly in pavucontrol or that a month ago when I was fixing a driver issue I ran a command that was something along the lines of "kill pulseaudio -rm .(and some other things I dont remember)". Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.